# Yarn workspace dependency isn't updated in vite cache

Tags: node-modules, vite, yarn-workspaces

TLDR: Vite is not updating workspace dependencies in the `node_modules/.vite` cache.

I am running a vite server locally and use yarn workspaces to organise my project.

My (simplified) directory:

```
web/              # @my_app workspace
  frontend/       # @my_app/frontend workspace
    App.tsx
    node_modules/
      .vite/      # the vite cache
  backend/
  shared/
    foo.ts
```

In the frontend I use constants defined in `shared/foo.ts`.

If I define a new constant `export const bar = 1` in `foo.ts`, try to import it from `App.tsx`, and run `vite` locally, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/@my_app_foo.js?v=cccdb61c' does not provide an export named 'bar' (at App.tsx)
```

Indeed, if I check the file `/node_modules/.vite/deps/@my_app_foo.js`, I can see it's not updated with my latest changes.

How do I make vite update the cached dependency when I make changes?

Note: The concerned dependencies don't change very often, so they don't need to be hot-reloaded on update (just need the cache to be up-to-date when I run vite).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vite prebundles dependencies and caches them locally in `node_modules/.vite/deps`.

There are two ways to force vite to rebundle the workspace dependency every time:

1. `vite --force`.
   This will update the bundled dependencies in `node_modules/.vite` every time you run vite locally (and the deps will be in `node_modules/.vite/deps_temp` instead of `deps`).
2. In `vite.config.js`, configure the bundle optimisation:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  optimizeDeps: { exclude: ['@my_app'] },
  // ...
});
```

This will exclude the `@my_app` workspace content from the `node_modules/.vite` cache.

Both solutions worked for the issue I was facing.